# IIS Worker Process - Application Pool Memory Issues

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET MVC internal website. I have seen the IIS Worker Process memory grow and grow until finally the website errors out. I have been doing some simple troubleshooting for memory leaks. I have change my code to minimum:

```
@using Intranet.Models
@model dynamic

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    Layout = null;
}

Test
```

When I hit refresh the IIS Worker Process memory usage increases after every refresh even with the simple code above. I am currently restarting the IIS service nightly, but at mid afternoon the memory % on the server is over 95%.

Would it help to set some memory caps in the Application pool in IIS?
What else should I be looking at?

I am running Windows 2012 but also testing on Windows 2019 with the same results.

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 0):

Is your memory usage is always more than 95% or it goes down and up?

open iis worker process and dobule click on it to check the currently executing requests.
I suggest you could collect some dump files and analyze them. 
Refer this article for more detail: 
[link1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/893660/quick-things-to-check-when-you-experience-high-memory-levels-in-asp-ne) , [link2](https://www.meadow.se/wordpress/debugging-a-memory-leak-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application/)

you could also try iis application pool recycling when memory limits are exceeded.